# My voice sounds high pitched on calls, what could be the issue?

Tags: usb, audio, microphone, webcam

My customers say that sometimes my voice sounds like I inhaled helium "like a smurf" they say, very small tiny voice!

I have a fairly new computer (i5 8400 desktop), about 3-4 years old.

Have brand new microphones (professional condenser), brand new webcam (Logitech c920 via USB), tried brand new Logitech headset (via 3.5), brand new Samsung mobile phone headset. Also tried USB external sound card.

Running Windows 10 with intel driver assistant, all up to date.

What else could this be? The motherboard? It's an AsRock Pro4.

Is the motherboard the culprit?

Comment: This doesn't explain the cause,  but a workaround: use an audio equalizer, whether already installed in Windows 10 (https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/windows-10-equalizer-what-is-it-and-how-does-it-work/), or a third party app, such as as free Equalizer APO (https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/files/). Set it to improve the sound from your input devices, each of which which can be configured separately. Suggestion: use two PC's, go online on one and listen to the other through headphones to check settings.

Comment: Using another PC is a great idea! Problem is, this problem is inconsistent. Usually I get on a call with the client, sometimes my voice sounds like chipmunk to him, I hang up, and try the call again, and then voice is ok

Comment: Two more possibilities: 1. On occasion, the PC connects to the *internal* microphone. Check which is being used when you notice an issue. 2. How are you connecting? Zoom? Google Meet? Microsoft Teams? Self-hosted (https://alternativeto.net/category/productivity/video-conferencing/?platform=self-hosted)? Try a different service, at least as a test -- the service host may be compressing audio unacceptably.

Comment: what platform are you using to *get on a call* - as for `Is the motherboard the culprit?` - almost no chance of that, since you've used both 3.5mm and USB devices for your microphone - I'd never say it's impossible though ... but it's impossible

Answer (score 0):

I bought an entire new computer, speakers, and microphone, problem solved!